# What does it mean by "Get Handle" in MFC

Tags: mfc

In a book about MFC I found "The GetDC function retrieves a handle to a display device context (DC) for the client area of a specified window or for the entire screen. You can use the returned handle in subsequent GDI functions to draw in the DC."

My question is what does it mean by "Handle" ? I am from C# background so it will be helpful if anyone can relate "Handle" with any C# concept if there's one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply: A handle is like a pointer, except there is an intermediate layer that turns the handle into an actual memory location (which may move around).

This is useful when you have managed or virtual memory.